# Is there any easy way to get likes of user from facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, restfb

I have to fetch likes of user for music,movies,actor category. I am using fql query like

```
queries.put("likers", "SELECT page_id FROM page_fan WHERE uid=me() AND type='MOVIE' ");

            JsonObject object = facebookClient.executeFqlMultiquery(queries, JsonObject.class);
```

Getting response

```
  [{"page_id":"216410885045047"},{"page_id":"312206562323313"},{"page_id":"68003267181"},{"page_id":"390508414453352"},{"page_id":"265574733639237"}]}
```

Basically i have two question here

```
1) How to write fql query to get page name. 
2) is there any way to get page_names from list of page id ?
```

I am using rest fb client for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/me/likes` would be the correct API endpoint to get user likes. Don´t use FQL anymore, it is deprecated since a very long time and will stop working soon: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

For some categories, there is a more direct endpoint, for example: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/movies/

All endpoints of the user can be found in the API reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user

Comment: How can i find likes by category here,i was trying using me/likes?category=Movie,but is returning all types.

Comment: Thanks, much helpful.

Comment: there is another question related to this,please have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37385002/how-to-post-html-content-in-facebook

Comment: that´s not at all related to this question, you should not cross-post other threads ;)